# How to get request parameter as hour with format AM/PM

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have to create rest endpoint which accepts parameters as hour with format AM/PM. I thought to use String with pattern validation:

```
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> get(
    @RequestParam
    @Pattern("Here regex which match something like this: 9am") String hourFrom, 
    @RequestParam
    @Pattern() String hourTo)
```

Do you have better idea how to resolve this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@DateTimeFormat` annotation (with custom pattern value) before `LocalTime` request parameter should do the trick.

```
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> get(
    @RequestParam
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "ha") LocalTime from, 
    @RequestParam
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "ha") LocalTime to)
```

Note: the actual request parameter must use uppercase AM/PM, so for example `"6PM"`